# Obligation to file US tax returns if I have 401k and Health Savings Account

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, 401k

I recently left a job in the USA year. This year I will have to file a tax return due to the income I earned in the USA. However, if I leave my 401k and HSA untouched in the USA, will I be obliged to file a tax return year after year simply due to their existence? Or would I only be obliged when I begin withdrawing money?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so--you have no income, no need to file.

Comment: Does this mean that you are no longer a U.S. resident?

Answer (score 2):

**Having** 401k or HSA is not income and doesn't trigger filing requirements. **Withdrawing** from 401k or HSA does. Also, in some States, HSA gains are taxed as investment income, so if you have gains in an HSA and you're a resident of such a State - you'll need to file a State tax return and pay taxes on the gains.

Comment: You might want to clarify the last sentence - I read it as, "If you have gains in your HSA, *even if you don't touch them*, you may need to file a State tax return."  But it's a bit unclear, just because of the first two sentences.

Comment: You read it exactly right.